# LinkedIn media upload 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am integrating linkedIn API. In order to post media with share, I'd have to follow steps mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share

Whenever I upload binary file to the "uploadUrl" I get 502 Bad Gateway, but if I use asset URN provided while sharing, the media is shown with post as binary file is uploaded.

What could possibly be the reason for this Bad Gateway?

Here is the POSTMAN image for registering upload
[image]

Here is the result after uploading media to that specific uploadUrl
[image]

What possibly could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include the Authorization: Bearer header along with your POST request to submit the binary.

[image: postman]